# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTCameraRollManager.getPhotos')

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

I want to use CameraRoll to get a picture but broken by red-screen.

So I tried following:

```
//print: undefined
console.log(RCTCameraRollManager);
```

[red-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I776.png)

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  Both on android and ios. Using react-native-0.12.0

Answer (score 15):

Please check if RCTCameraRoll is added to your library. If not you must link the library to from `node_module/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll`

There is great guide to linking libraries to react-native in the react-native docs
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#content

Answer (score 3):

Being an android developer, I was struggling to use the react-native camera roll. I was able to find it in following location :-

```
node_module/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll
```

And while linking the library using "react-native link cameraRoll , I was facing the following error:-

```
npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-cameraroll
```

So we need to manually link it as follows:

open your Xcode.Then from the node_module/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll, drag the RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj into the left side pane of Libraries folder. 
Now go to Project - general --"Linked frameworks and libraries"
add (+) the folder named libRCTCameraRoll.a.

Re-install and it works.